# Verify if required fields has values on click on upload button in vue.js

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, file-upload

I have made a code below that allow the users to upload a `.csv` file, but before he can upload any file, I would like to make some validations: like if he has already chosen some required input. And I don't know how to do it.

```html
<input type="file" accept=".csv" ref="file" v-on:input="handleUpload()" id="upload-csv" />
```

This is the display in the UI, which are required fields:

```
<div class="list-filter box-fill" style="text-align: center;">

  <a @click="filter('date')" :class="{ active :  active_col == 'date'}">
      <label>date</label>
      <span>{{this.csvDate}}</span>
  </a>
  <a @click="filter('name')" :class="{ active : active_col == 'name'}">
      <label>name</label>
      <span>{{this.csvName}}</span>
  </a>
  <a @click="filter('start_time')" :class="{ active : active_col == 'start_time'}">
      <label>start_time</label>
      <span>{{this.csvStart}}</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

User will just select letters from A-AZ.

```
data(){
    return{
        csvDate:'',
        csvName:'',
        csvStart:'',
    }
},
methods:{
    handleUpload(){
        //do the verification here
        if(this.csvDate == '' || this.csvName == '' || this.csvStart == ''){
             console.log("Input required fields.");
        }
    },
}
```

But this one is only triggered after selecting the file. What I want is to verify the required fields on-click the upload button.

Comment: `<input type="file" :disabled="csvDate == '' || csvName == '' || csvStart == ''" accept=".csv" ref="file" v-on:input="handleUpload()" id="upload-csv" />`

Comment: But what I would recommend is making a Computed Value with the type Boolean so you can check for verification on different parts of your Page without needing to repeat the same code.